# How to animate a paragraph in Flutter using TypeWriterAnimation for the entire paragraph at once?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-text

I'm currently working on a Flutter project and I'm facing an issue with animations. Specifically, I'm trying to animate a paragraph, but I'm using the TypeWriterAnimation package, which animates the text line by line. However, I'd like to achieve a different effect.

Is there a way to animate the entire paragraph on the screen simultaneously, using the same TypeWriterAnimation or any other method? I want all the lines of the paragraph to appear at the same time with the animation.

Thank you for your help!

[image: SS of the text]

[LINK : Short recording of the animation](https://i.imgur.com/20rua37.mp4) (*this is not what i want.* What i want is all three lines should animate at the same time on the screen)

Comment: use this package animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a TweenAnimationBuilder>LinearGradiend>Text and now the whole paragraph is animated.